# How to get the payment with the entity_id from Webhook

Tags: square-connect

I don't find a way
I already try to get directly from 'https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/location_id/transactions/entity_id'
I already try to find the tender_id on [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITrwe.png)

I'm more than 5 days on this, i'm going crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `entity_id` is equal to the V1 `payment_id`. You can pass the `entity_id` to the V1 [RetrievePayment](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#get-paymentid) endpoint in order to retrieve the payment information.

*Note that V1 `payment_id` == V2 `tender_id` (inside of a `Transaction` object).*